# How to aligh in the centre of the screen with Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm using Sencha Touch, at the moment I'm adding to the view some HTML code and underneath a button. I would like have the content of the HTML code together with the button to be in the centre of the screen.

Could you suggest me how to do it? thanks for your time

```
Ext.define('Project.view.SettingsSuccess', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'settingformsuccess',

    config: {
        title: 'Settings',
        iconCls: 'info',
        cls: 'settings-success',
        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,

        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Settings',

            items: [                
            {
                xtype: 'spacer'
            }, 
            {
                text: 'Back',
                ui: 'back'
            }
            ]
        },

        {
            html: [
            '<p>You have successfully authorised.</p>'
            ].join("")
        },

        // Go to Dashboard Button
        {
            xtype:'button',
            text: 'Visit your Home Page',
            ui: 'normal'
        }  
        ]

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

Pack the Html Content and the Button in a Container:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.container.Container

Place the Container where you want, see the setPosition(..) Method: 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Component3.html#Ext-Component-method-setPosition